# How to change DNS settings in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, dns

I want to develop an application for iPhone. I have developed some apps before. I need to change DNS settings. Is it possible and how can I do and if it's possible, is it applicable only to wi-fi ? I want to change it for wi-fi and 3G, EDGE, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the iPhone/iPad's DNS settings. Such behaviour could be horribly abused, and it'd affect all other apps on the system.